# Unable to load external files in java while running in terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, classpath, config

I have created a executable jar package (called myjar.jar) which has a class for reading config file(called config_reader) .There is another class file outside myjar.jar which uses the config_reader. But the config file for config_reader is placed outside the myjar.jar ( in local filesystem) .Now when i try to execute the executable jar along with another file that uses it i get an error saying config file not found : 

I tried to :
java -classpath  config myclass.class

can Anyone help out on this ?

The code of  config_reader is :

```
public class config_reader()
{
     public static ArrayList<String> get_prop()
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        ArrayList<String> s= new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
               //load a properties file

            prop.load(new FileInputStream("config"));

               //get the property value and print it out
               s.add(prop.getProperty("source_folder_dir"));
               s.add(prop.getProperty("dest_folder_dir"));
               s.add(prop.getProperty("file_type"));
               s.add(prop.getProperty("username"));
               s.add(prop.getProperty("userpwd"));
               s.add(prop.getProperty("exclusion_list"));


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config"));
```

Instead of just saying `config` use absolute path to the file. Infact it is better to do

```
    File configFile = new File("absolute path to config file");
    if(configFile.exists()){
        //continue with your logic
    }
```

Comment: But here  the location of config file is not permanent .  Is there any way in which I can get the current working directory and then refer to relative location of config file ?

Comment: try **config_reader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()** to get current directory path.